# Segfault with operator() for KiFMM when using MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, petsc

I am using KiFMM and PETSc for my code. It had no problems for the serial version, but when I am trying to use MPI with 2 nodes I am now getting an error at `(*trgPos)(j,i)`, which is of type `DblNumMat` as seen here:
http://www.mrl.nyu.edu/~harper/kifmm3d/documentation/common/html/nummat_8hpp_18ed51e81f911a23442591467d7a83ca.html.

The backtrace from gdb shows this:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000070761e in NumMat<double>::operator() (this=0x0, i=0, j=0)
at /directory/src/Onepart/../../inc/KIFMM3D/common/nummat.hpp:101
101      assert( i>=0 && i<_m && j>=0 && j<_n );
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x000000000070761e in NumMat<double>::operator() (this=0x0, i=0, j=0)
at /directory/src/Onepart/../../inc/KIFMM3D/common/nummat.hpp:101
```

Anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
NumMat<double>::operator() (this=0x0, i=0, j=0)
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

This shows that you are calling the `operator()` through a NULL pointer and should already hint you that `trgPos` is that NULL pointer. You should examine the code and trace the code path that each rank takes. It must be that in some cases `trgPos` is not properly initialised or it could be that the memory allocation operator is failing due to lack of memory.